# unable to setup a project using vite

Tags: vite

I want to try vite, but when I try  `npm init @vitejs/app` it throws an error saying
"Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\username'
command not found: create-app
"
what could be the reason? I have vite installed through npm

Answer (score 0):

Vite init command changed to `npm init vite@latest`. From [this PR](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/4216). And the [docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project).